# ctrl-c being inserted into command line

Tags: bash

I'm using Centos 6, bash version 4.1.2.

In my old centos 5 box (I don't have it any longer), I could type part way through a command, and when I discovered I didn't want to run that command, I would hit ctrl-c to cancel and get a new line on the prompt.

With my new install, if I hit ctrl-c while typing up a command I actually get a '^C' inserted in the current position of the line before the command cancels and a new prompt line is available.

No big deal, but if I go back through my history its now full of commands with '^C' in them, which is something I'd like to avoid because I use my history a lot.

So, any idea how I can use ctrl-c to cancel, but not get a '^C' inserted in the line?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks, but I'm using ctrl-c because I want to keep the command as I typed it visible in case I want to copy-paste in a few minutes.   My question is about a change of behaviour when using ctrl-c.

Comment: If you use `Ctrl-U`, you can paste it later with `Ctrl-Y`.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run `history` or hit Up Arrow, you actually see "^C" in the commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/147013/how-to-disable-c-from-being-echoed-on-linux-on-ctrl-c), this is what you need to do to get back to the old behaviour of ctrl+c:

```
stty -echoctl
```

I've just tried it on my own CentOs 6 machine and verified that it does what (I think) you're looking for :)